# Calculation Optimal Value

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a task to calculate the optimal value for a set of values or data.
I've found the attached algorithm to calculate the k as optimum value and write the following code in javascript, but it doesn't work. could you please help me in finding the right way for calculating the optimal value and what are the mistakes in the code? (this method to know the optimal value for customer consumption of gas during the whole year the values are taken every half an hour )

```
const pulses=[31, 37, 34, 32, 32, 33, 41, 32, 33, 32, 39, 43, 37, 32, 33, 33, 31, 27, 33, 25, 25, 25, 26, 30, 26, 29, 30, 24, 25, 24, 31, 28, 22, 22, 22, 25, 32, 33, 24, 22, 22, 21, 23, 22, 25, 28, 22, 22, 21, 25, 31, 23, 22, 22, 24, 31, 23, 22, 23, 26, 25, 21, 25, 32, 25, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 33, 25,   24, 24, 24, 30, 29, 25, 24, 24, 30, 28, 25, 24, 25, 28, 33, 31, 29, 34, 36, 26, 25, 26, 25, 27, 32, 27, 27];

let i=pulses.indexOf();
let overR=0;
let lessR=0;
let k;
overRate = ()=>
{ 
  overR=(pulses[i+1] - k+overR); 
  return overR
};

lessRate = ()=>
{ 
  lessR=(pulses[i+1] - k+lessR); 
  return lessR
};

for(let i=0; i<pulses.length; i++)
{
  if(pulses[i+1]!==pulses[i]) 
  {
    k = pulses[i].valueOf()
  }

  if(pulses[i+1] > k)
  { 
    overRate()
  }
  else if(pulses[i+1]<k)
  { 
    lessRate()
  };
}
if (overR>lessR) 
{  
  k = k + ((overR - lessR)/2);
};
console.log(k);
```

Comment: Where have you _found the attached algorithm_?

Comment: my friend sent it to me, but it's just a proposal, he is not sure about it.

Comment: Based on which criterion do you consider a value to be _optimal_?

Comment: the optimal  value is the best value when the customer reaches it, the company will start to supply gas from other sources so he avoids paying any penalties after this value, we calculate it depending on his consumptions during one year for example

Comment: Are you aware that `lessR` is not positive?

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation _the optimal value is the best value …_ is insufficient. _he avoids paying any penalties after this value_ - so does he pay penalties before this value? How do you want to _calculate it_? How shall we find the errors in your code if you don't clearly specify what it is supposed to do?

Comment: thank you too much, I've solved the problem. It was a mistake in the principle of the algorithm, I got it and it worked.